# Type Conversion show omits the leading 0

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I am learning javascript and came across this while reading the topic TypeConversions.

```
alert(Number(" 0123 ")); //brings out 123
```

I was wondering why it brings out 123 and not 0123. Can somebody explain why?

What should i do bring the leading 0 in too?

Comment: Because the numerical value is 123. The string is converted to that numerical value and then displayed and an integer type doesn't store information on leading zeros. That's a formatting concern.

Comment: Why just one leadig zero? Why not two? Or three? Or? ...?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Leading zeros are removed when you convert a string to number as they don't have any mathematical meaning. To print the number with leading zeros you always need to print it as a string only. Or you can design your own custom data-structure which returns both string value and number value, based on what you require.